# django timeout file upload

Tags: python, django, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3

Hey I am trying to do a simple `manage.py collectstatic` that uploads to s3 which is in the aws china region. The problem I am having is the process stops halfway and then gives this error

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/srv/bnn/env/bin/manage.py", line 6, in <module>
    exec(compile(open(__file__).read(), __file__, 'exec'))
  File "/srv/bnn/content/scripts/manage.py", line 12, in <module>
    execute_from_command_line(argv)
  File "/srv/bnn/env/lib/python3.5/site-packages/django/core/management/__init__.py", line 363, in execute_from_command_line
    utility.execute()
  File "/srv/bnn/env/lib/python3.5/site-packages/django/core/management/__init__.py", line 355, in execute
    self.fetch_command(subcommand).run_from_argv(self.argv)
  File "/srv/bnn/env/lib/python3.5/site-packages/django/core/management/base.py", line 283, in run_from_argv
    self.execute(*args, **cmd_options)
  File "/srv/bnn/env/lib/python3.5/site-packages/django/core/management/base.py", line 330, in execute
    output = self.handle(*args, **options)
  File "/srv/bnn/env/lib/python3.5/site-packages/django/contrib/staticfiles/management/commands/collectstatic.py", line 199, in handle
    collected = self.collect()
  File "/srv/bnn/env/lib/python3.5/site-packages/django/contrib/staticfiles/management/commands/collectstatic.py", line 139, in collect
    for original_path, processed_path, processed in processor:
  File "/srv/bnn/env/lib/python3.5/site-packages/pipeline/storage.py", line 62, in post_process
    for name, hashed_name, processed in super_class.post_process(paths.copy(), dry_run, **options):
  File "/srv/bnn/env/lib/python3.5/site-packages/pipeline/storage.py", line 39, in post_process
    for name, hashed_name, processed in super_class.post_process(paths.copy(), dry_run, **options):
  File "/srv/bnn/env/lib/python3.5/site-packages/django/contrib/staticfiles/storage.py", line 414, in post_process
    for post_processed in all_post_processed:
  File "/srv/bnn/env/lib/python3.5/site-packages/django/contrib/staticfiles/storage.py", line 246, in post_process
    for name, hashed_name, processed, _ in self._post_process(paths, adjustable_paths, hashed_files):
  File "/srv/bnn/env/lib/python3.5/site-packages/django/contrib/staticfiles/storage.py", line 312, in _post_process
    hashed_name = self.hashed_name(name, content_file)
  File "/srv/bnn/env/lib/python3.5/site-packages/django/contrib/staticfiles/storage.py", line 109, in hashed_name
    file_hash = self.file_hash(clean_name, content)
  File "/srv/bnn/env/lib/python3.5/site-packages/django/contrib/staticfiles/storage.py", line 86, in file_hash
    for chunk in content.chunks():
  File "/srv/bnn/env/lib/python3.5/site-packages/django/core/files/base.py", line 76, in chunks
    self.seek(0)
ValueError: I/O operation on closed file.
```

But some of the files are ending up in s3. I also tried to do a pip install of boto on that ec2 instance and it too had a timeout error.

So my question is how to you change the timeouts for django so that it wont get a timeout error and then stop dong the collectstatic method?

Answer (score 0):

Using a custom StorageClass fixes the issue

in custom_storages.py:

```
from django.contrib.staticfiles.storage import ManifestFilesMixin
from storages.backends.s3boto3 import S3Boto3Storage, SpooledTemporaryFile
import os

class CustomS3Boto3Storage(ManifestFilesMixin, S3Boto3Storage):
    def _save_content(self, obj, content, parameters):
        """
        We create a clone of the content file as when this is passed to boto3 it wrongly closes
        the file upon upload where as the storage backend expects it to still be open
        """
        # Seek our content back to the start
        content.seek(0, os.SEEK_SET)

        # Create a temporary file that will write to disk after a specified size
        content_autoclose = SpooledTemporaryFile()

        # Write our original content into our copy that will be closed by boto3
        content_autoclose.write(content.read())

        # Upload the object which will auto close the content_autoclose instance
        super(CustomS3Boto3Storage, self)._save_content(obj, content_autoclose, parameters)

        # Cleanup if this is fixed upstream our duplicate should always close
        if not content_autoclose.closed:
            content_autoclose.close()


class StaticStorage(CustomS3Boto3Storage):
    location = settings.STATICFILES_LOCATION
```

in you settings:

```
STATICFILES_LOCATION = 'static'
STATICFILES_STORAGE = 'custom_storages.StaticStorage'
```

Credit goes to [charlesthk](https://github.com/jschneier/django-storages/issues/382#issuecomment-377174808)

This [github issue](https://github.com/jschneier/django-storages/issues/382) has a lot of useful information about this problem.